# How can I load sqlite file into oracle 11g?

Tags: spatialite, oracle-spatial

I have SQLite file which I have taken it from Sptialite DB. I need to convert this file into SDO. Plz help me

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Have you tried anything? This sort of question, please give me a library, code, is generally frowned upon, as it shows no effort. Here is an [Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190660/sqlite-to-oracle) that might help get you started.

Comment: ogr2ogr will do it

Comment: @iant. I am starting to realize that ogr2ogr does everything. I wish the docs were a bit more volumninous, sometimes, though.-

Comment: @iant. I tried in ogr2ogr but in that there is option to export oracle directly..

Comment: You need to have GDAL with OCI support. It is not compiled by default because you must explicitly agree with the terms. Gisinternals.com has a plugin with installer if you are on Windows.

Comment: Osgeo4w has it included if you have oracle installed

Answer (score 4):

You can use OGR2OGR to do this, writing to Oracle is through the [OCI](http://www.gdal.org/drv_oci.html) driver; reading from SpatialLite is by through the [SQLite](http://www.gdal.org/drv_sqlite.html) driver so something like:

```
ogr2ogr -f OCI OCI:warmerda/password@gdal800.dreadfest.com db.sqlite
```

should do it.